# Pretrib or prewrath based on a correct understanding of Revelation 6:17?

Tags: greek, revelation

Revelation 6:17 NIV

> For the great day of their wrath has come, and who can stand?

According to BSBGrk INT (Bible software program "The Word") "has come" is an Aorist Indicative Active.
Does that mean past tense: all the way back to the first seal? Or is the moment of their wrath at hand: after the sixth seal?
Saying it another way: is the Aorist always past tense?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: This question requires more clarity and detail as it seems to be written in an esoteric shorthand known only to specific devotees. The site is open to all English speakers, world-wide and to all interested parties. 'Pretrib' and 'prewrath' need explanation for the unititiated and a proper argument requires to be stated that the question should not remain obscure.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, aorist is not a tense of the Greek verb but an aspect of the verb.  Having said that, when translating Greek verbs, one must still choose a tense when converting to English.

"Aorist" means "undefined" and thus, the aspect is undefined.  This means that the aorist does not define whether the action is perfect or imperfect, completed, incomplete, or anything else.  It simply specifies an action.

In the case of the prophecies of Rev 6, all the six seals begin with a phrase containing an aorist indicative verb (watched, opened, looked, heard, etc), which cannot be translated with anything other than (in this case) a past-tense English verb.

This is not always the case.  Indeed, Rev 6:17 contains two verbs, both aorist:

- the first is ἦλθεν which is aorist infinitive active and indicates a past tense, "has come".
- the second is σταθῆναι which is aorist infinitive passive.  Now aorist infinitives almost always have an associated verb or participle which give the tense.  In this case it is δύναται which is present indicative; thus σταθῆναι must be translated in the present tense.

Thus, most English version translate the verse Rev 6:17 correctly:

> because the great day of Their wrath has come, and who is able to
> stand?"

Thus, the entire description of the six seals is described with aorist indicative verbs - a rather simple description of what John saw.  Since John saw something and reported what he saw, he reports it in the past tense.

Hermeneutically, this important question is answered in the next two verse - the only ones able to stand are those having "*the seal of the living God.*"

The question about pre-tib vs post-trib etc, is a theological and eschatological question that is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: I appreciate your exposition of the aorist. Very thankful.

Comment: + 1 I would add that demurring on the theological controversy is wise, as this part of the q is  a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ad another text in reply of Dottard's answer: Mark 14:41 (NIV):"Returning the third time, he said to them, “Are you still sleeping and resting? Enough! The hour has come. Look, the Son of Man is delivered into the hands of sinners." The hour has come is the exact same Greek (Aorist Indicative Active.). Isn't it clear from this text that the hour is at hand and not past tense?

Comment: "has come" in Mark 14:41 should be translated (as most versions do) that the hour has come - that it, it has arrived.

Comment: @Verbeek777 this forum works a little differently from many.  Why not post your reasonable remark as a comment to Dottard's answer? Otherwise, your post isn't an answer per se to the OP question, and that's all we should post here as an 'answer', at least as I understand it.